# Multi series line graph in GRAFANA

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I am trying to develop a multi series line graph in grafana with mysql queries.

Here I had two mysql query , but the graphs appear in continuous manner and not in multi series line manner.

Below I pasted the graph.
[image]

Here the x-axis (months) are repeating and the graph is not overlapping. Kindly suggest for this.

Below I pasted the two queries

Query A:

```sql
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'january'`
where Source='Doors'
group by status
UNION
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'feburary'`
where Source='Doors'
group by status
UNION
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'march'`
where Source='Doors'
group by status
UNION
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'april'`
where Source='Doors'
group by status
UNION
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'may'`
where Source='Doors'
group by status;
```

QueryB:

```sql
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'january'`
where Source='RTC'
group by status
UNION
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'feburary'`
where Source='RTC'
group by status
UNION
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'march'`
where Source='RTC'
group by status
UNION
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'april'`
where Source='RTC'
group by status
UNION
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_Date) as time_sec,
  count(status) as value,
  month as metric
FROM `'may'`
where Source='RTC'
group by status;
```

Answer (score 0):

currently it does not support multi line graph. Take a look at here.
[click this link and see the issue](https://community.grafana.com/t/line-graph-issue-influxdb/1885)

Comment: This should be a comment. As the said functionality is not yet supported, the requirement needs to be met in some other way. You need to describe that solution and then refer to online documents as a further read